# Unity generates bad mipmap, making voxel terrains look bad

Tags: unity, rendering, voxels

It's just a **dirt terrain** with **grass blocks** on the **top**. *(which are just dirt blocks with green tops.)*

I sampled a Unity terrain's heightmap, and constructed a voxel terrain based on it, and divided it into chunks, whose meshes then were combined.

Sadly the **generated mipmaps are bad**, the mipmap change is easily noticeable: first the **shade of green changes**, then it **fully becomes dirt colored**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are several ways to create blocky terrain in Unity. You might get better answers if you told us how you implemented it. Is it a 3rd party asset? Did you create your own? Did you hack the Unity terrain system to do this?

Comment: @Philipp I looped through a Unity Terrain's height map, and based on the height, I created columns made out of unit cubes.
Then I created chunks from the unit cubes, and then combined the chunks' unit cubes into a single mesh.

Comment: So you are saying that all the environment we see on that screenshot is one single mesh?

Comment: It could be a mipmapping problem.

Comment: @Philipp No, a few hundred meshes. The map contains millions of cubes, but the map is divided into multiple X*Y*Z sized chunks, whose cubes are combined, thus 1 chunk = 1 mesh.

Comment: And I assume that those texture problems don't occur specifically at the chunk borders but inside the chunks? Maybe it's a problem with how you generated your UV maps?

Comment: Also @user253751 might be on to something. Can you show us your textures and their import settings?

Comment: Yes, it was a mipmapping issue. I turned off generate MipMap and now it works. But then it's noise, obviously :\ I added a screenshot to the original post.

Comment: In a scene like that you should definitely use mip maps. Instead of just giving up on mip mapping completely you might want to try to find out why Unity generated such weird mip maps.

Comment: Have you considered painting your own mipmaps, so you can control exactly how deep the chain goes and which parts are allowed/forbidden to bleed?

Comment: Yes, I think I will do that. Or maybe texture the cube differently, maybe Unity will generate better ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that Unity generates mip maps from your texture without considering the "cell borders" in your textures (how could it at the texture importing stage when it does not yet know how you are going to set up your UV maps?). So the brown parts of the textures bleed into the green parts.

A quick and dirty solution would be to turn off mip map generation, but that will likely result in a performance penalty (and in a scene like that you need any performance you can get) and other kinds of visual artifacts.

So a better solution could be to use three separate texture images - one for the sides of the cubes, one for the top and one for the bottom. That will prevent the mipmap generation algorithm from mixing these textures.

Comment: Is that doable in Unity or I have to make a cube in a modelling software, and texture it with 3 different textures files?

Comment: @Tudvari Don't you generate procedural meshes anyway? You might want to look into how to do that with more than one material.

Comment: Hmm, I think making a better model would be better performance wise

Comment: Now I created my own model, with padding (the padding is rgba (0,0,0,0)), and now it looks better, but there are still issues, like at mid-distance and at very far away: https://i.imgur.com/0xoHCUW.png

Comment: @Tudvari It's likely still the same problem: The different zones of your texture bleed into each other when Unity scales the texture down in order to create the mip-maps. To fix this problem, create a model which uses separate materials with separate textures for the top, the sides and the bottom. Use textures which are only one 16x16 square.